# How can I have two buttons in the bottom using align widget inside the center and column widgets?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a grouped button with two individuals and place them in the bottom. It is a login screen so there are other things.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
              ),
              Text('Login'),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('login');
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('signup');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've been trying with like align bottom and stuffs. But with `Row()`, it does not work with Center + Column widget. How can I send these two buttons to the bottom of the Center widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. One of them is to use the `Spacer` widget:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Text('Login'),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('login');
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('signup');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Another one would be to reverse the column and start from the bottom, but most probably the side effects are not wanted.

Also, one option would be to divide the whole screen into fixed height partitions with the help of MediaQuery.of(context).size.height value so that your buttons are always at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
              ),
              Text('Login'),
              Expanded(
                child:Container
                  (
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('login');
                        },
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('signup');
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )

               )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```